# How elaborate pyspark code with sacala code?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark-sql

I want to transform this Scala code in Pyspark code.

Scala Code:

```
Row={
  val columnArray = new Array[String](95)
  columnArray(0)=x.substring(0,10)
  columnArray(1)=x.substring(11,14)
  columnArray(2)=x.substring(15,17)
  Row.fromSeq(columnArray)
}
```

How elaborate same scala code on pyspark?

Comment: What did you actually try? Adding it to your question will help people to answer your specific question.

Answer (score 1):

@Felipe Avalos
@Nicolas Grenié
*Assuming you are trying to convert an array of strings to a data frame with substrings as the corresponding columns this will do the trick in pyspark.*

Change the column_array to have the array of strings and the column_names to have the names of each column:

```
    column_array = ["abcdefghijklmnopqrst", "abcdefghijklmnopqrst"]
    column_names = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]
```

This will convert map the array to an rdd with the strings and substrings as the value. The rdd is then converted to a data frame with the column names given.

```
    sc.parallelize(column_array).map(lambda x: (x, x[0:10], x[11:14], 
    x[15:17])).toDF(column_names).show()
```

This will generate the following data frame:

```
    +--------------------+----------+----+----+
    |                col1|      col2|col3|col4|
    +--------------------+----------+----+----+
    |abcdefghijklmnopqrst|abcdefghij| lmn|  pq|
    |abcdefghijklmnopqrst|abcdefghij| lmn|  pq|
    +--------------------+----------+----+----+
```

Comment: Hi @karhershey, while this may answer the question it's usually recommended to add a bit more context and explanation around your code sample.